# Why cant I add Configured Product, Grouped Product and Bundle Product in another Bundle Product in Magento 2

Tags: magento

I have created a Configurable Product, Grouped Product and a Bundle Product in Magento, I want to include these three products in another new Bundle Product. But while I was creating a new magento Bundle Product, there were only **Simple Products** & **Virtual Products** included in the **Bundle items** option. There were no **Configurable Products**, **Grouped products** & **Bundle Products**.

I am facing difficulties while doing the above task, can anyone help me with the issue?[The issue has been shown diagramatically here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHtYT.jpg)

Thanks..

Comment: In default magento you can only create bundle with simple and virtual product.see here official Magento User Guide http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-bundle.html

Comment: @Kul when i did further research on the same issue i found this information http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5002/multiple-configurable-products-as-a-bundle. have a look at it. it says configurable products can be added to grouped products. but in magento back-end grouped product also allows only simple & virtual products to be added in the group.

Comment: @Nagraj basavraj Yes I see the answer but as i mentioned it's not possible in default magento. We can achieve may be by customization or using some module.

Comment: @Kul Thank You for the help